# Inheritance, Calling Methods from Sub-Classes

Tags: java

We were going over inheritance in my comp sci lecture today, and talking about accessing methods from other classes. One of my classmates asked how a sub-sub-class would access the highest parents classes method, and my prof was curious about it as well and suggested that something like:

```
super.super.toString();
```

Might be able to work, which it doesn't. And being curious I tried to figure this out on my own and came up with this:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        System.out.println(b.toString());
        System.out.println(c.toString());
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Class A";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public String toString(){
        return "Class B";
    }
}

class C extends B {
    public String toString(){
        return A.class.toString();
    }
}
```

Which worked out, now while testing various things I stumbled upon this: (This would all be done in the class C)

```
super.toString();
```

Seems to do the same thing as:

```
B.class.toString();
```

My question is there any difference between the two, or are they the exact same? Also in my code above this, is that the proper way to call a method from a sub-sub-class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not the same thing. Assuming you are calling `super.toString()` from your class `C`, this invokes `toString()` on `B`, which will return "Class B".

When you call `A.class.toString()` or `B.class.toString()` you are not invoking any superclass method at all, you are calling `toString` on `Class`.

Answer (score 3):

No, `B.class.toString()` will call the `toString()` method on the `Class` class. That's not even *slightly* the same thing as calling `super.toString()`.

There is no way of calling `A`'s implementation of `toString()` from `C`, bypassing `A`. That would break encapsulation, basically.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Parent{
   public void foo(){

   }
}


class Child extends Parent{

   @Override
   public void foo(){
       super.foo(); //will call the parent class foo method
   }
}

class ChildOfChild extends Child{

    public void bar(){
        super.foo(); //this actually is the method of the Parent that is actually called at the end as Child calls super.foo();
    }
}
```

`super.toString();` and `B.class.toString()` are totally different. In the later you are calling the `toString()` method of **class literal**.

As shown in the example if the sub-sub class calls a method defined in hierarchy then it depends on implementation which method will be called. If the immediate parent **overrides** that method and does not call `super.method()` then it(method of parent-of-parent) **cannot** be called. That is how inheritance works.

If the immediate parent did not override the method and you call method from sub-sub class then the method of the parent of immediate parent will be called.

Answer (score 1):

You will see very quickly if you try and access any state inside your toString() that you are not doing what you think you are doing.

SomeClass.class is a special construct. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2
For the exact definition.

You may not use super.super because Java is actually designed to force you to properly use objects and object oriented patterns. You should not be allowed to skip a parent class's implementation and therefore it is not allowed. This is actually one of the gripes about Java compared to other less strict languages but it does force you to really consider your class hierarchies and what you are doing.